# How to print to excel/csv?

Tags: python, excel, csv, printing

Current task is to pull only numbers from a text file. I have this part working and it's printing vertically in the console.

I'm trying to print my output to an CSV or Excel file. Preferably to the same column. Can I just replace my print line with `f.save()`?

```
import re
import xlwt

f = open('printouthg.csv','w')

file_name = r'C:\Users\hank\desktop\pycodes\numbers.txt'
with open(file_name, 'r') as file:
    filedata = file.read()

lines = filedata
import re
output = []
repl_str = re.compile('\d+.?\d*')
#t = r'\d+.?\d*'
line = lines.split()
for word in line:
    match = re.search(repl_str, word)
    if match:
        output.append(float(match.group()))

print(*output, sep='\n')
```

Comment: what do you mean by `f.save`? What are you asking, exactly? Have you searched for "how to create a csv in Python"?

Comment: Please show a sample of what the input file looks like and what you'd like to be the output (file?) to be. Note that there's a [`redirect_stdout()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.redirect_stdout) context manager in the `contextlib` module that can be used to redirect printed output somewhere else.

Comment: I was able to complete this task and updated the code above. I overthought having to read and write an entirely new file that wasn't my text file. Thought I could logically export the code and not have to open the csv. Thanks

 @martineau, the text file was simply "these are some words but 100 and some numbers 90.23 and some blahblah 73.99."- saved to a txt file.

Comment: @thehank: Read about [CSV File Reading and Writing](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#module-csv)

Comment: @thehank: It's very confusing to others for you to have edited your question and added an answer to it. IMO the best thing to do in this situation would be to post the code you added as an _answer_ and roll your question back to what it was previously. You can also accept your own answer afterwards.

Comment: I appended this code to the code above and this resolved my issue. 
    csv_data = '' 
    for i in output:
        csv_data += str(i)
        csv_data += ',\n'
#save to CSV file and append
    with open('outputhg.csv', 'w+') as file:
        filedata = file.write(csv_data)

Comment: @thehank: I know what you did, which was precisely why I made my last comment. It would be better for you to post the code that resolved the problem for you separately as an formal answer, _not_ put in your question like you did. That will make what's going on more understandable and helpful to others.